# Liquid Grouping Around Rigid Body Flow Effector

Tags: fluid-simulation, rigid-body-simulation, mantaflow

I have a simple fluid simulation set up with rigid bodies that collide with each other before the water flows. The rigid bodies also have a flow effector so that they will affect the water. It seems to work in the first hundredish frames but then the particles suddenly start bunching around the rigid bodies. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I do have a wind force field that affects the water, but I don't see why this would cause it to bunch up around the rigid bodies.

Thanks

[.blend file & animation](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XvvpFZtnIvJYkauoZ_hrMXco4GDoHBpE?usp=sharing)

picture:
[image: Liquid particles bunching around rigid body flow effectors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an effector that was causing it. It was pointed so that it would push the particles *away* from the cubes, but it is probably some weird quirk with blender (maybe the effect somehow "bouncing off" the liquid domain.